# Como puedo hacer que el segundo producto tambien pueda calcular el subtotal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando que el segundo producto haga lo mismo que el primero, es decir,
que dependiendo de las cantidades que ponga sume el subtotal pero no se ni por
donde empezar, la otra funcion tarde dia y medio en sacarla pero al final lo
consegui pero el problema que tengo aqui es que no se ni por donde empezar, no
quiero una solucion, me valdria con una orientacion o alguna pista para poder ir
tirando, la logica que estoy desarrollando es en calculateAll() alguna idea?
quizas apuntando a getelementbyid en vez de queryselector?

aqui pongo el codigo html con todas las tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
      <title>e-commerce</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <h1>e-commerce</h1>
      <table id="cart">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="product">
            <td class="name">
              <span> Rubber Duck</span>
            </td>
            <td class="price">$<span>25.00</span></td>
            <td class="quantity">
              <input type="number" class="i" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
            </td>
            <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
            <td class="action">
              <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!-- Iteration 2: Add more products here -->
          <tr class="product two">
            <td class="name">
              <span> Beach Towel</span>
            </td>
            <td class="price">$<span>12.50</span></td>
            <td class="quantity">
              <input type="number" class="i" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
            </td>
            <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
            <td class="action">
              <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <!-- <tr class="create-product">
              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="Product Price" />
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <button id="create" class="btn">Create Product</button>
              </td>
            </tr> -->
        </tfoot>
      </table>
      <p class="calculate-total">
        <button id="calculate" class="btn btn-success">Calculate Prices</button>
      </p>
      <h2 id="total-value">Total: $<span>0</span></h2>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

aqui pongo el archivo js donde meto la logica, la primera funcion hace lo que quiero , que el primer producto, dependiendo de los items que se quieran comprar, los sume, quisiera hacer lo mismo con el segundo produto pero no soy capaz

```
    // ITERATION 1
    
    function updateSubtotal(product) {
    
      const price = product.querySelector('.price span')
      const priceElement = parseInt(price.innerText)
    
      const quantity = product.querySelector('.i').value
      let quantityElement = quantity
    
      let subtotal = product.querySelector('.subtotal span')
      subtotal.innerText = priceElement * quantityElement
    
    }


    
    function calculateAll() {
    
      const singleProduct = document.querySelector('.product')
      console.log(singleProduct)
      updateSubtotal(singleProduct)
      console.log(updateSubtotal)
    
    }

       creo que tengo que cambiar el documento.querySelector para que no apunte en 
         ambos casos a product, la verdad que estoy atascadisimo en este punto
```

Comment: Orientación: Para calcularlos todos busca información sobre **querySelectorAll()** para recorrer todos los elementos que compartan el selector deseado e ir sumándolos en tu función calculateAll().  En cuanto al segundo producto, plánteate usar addEventListener() para lanzar la función updateSubotal() sobre el elemento/fila/subtotal adecuado cuando el valor del input con clase **i** elegido cambie.

Answer (score 0):

Era mucho más simple de lo que pensaba....

```
function calculateAll() {

  const singleProduct = document.querySelector('.rubber')
  const secondProduct = document.querySelector('.beach')


  updateSubtotal(singleProduct)
  updateSubtotal(secondProduct)
}
```

Comment: Buen día, que bueno que encontraste una solución a tu propia pregunta, por favor agrega una explicación sobre el por qué esta es la solución y acepta tu propia respuesta.

Comment: buenas! pues el fallo que tenía es que no estaba llamando al segundo pregunta ya que tenía puesto updateSubtotal(singleProduct, secondProduct) y tenía que llamar dos veces a la primera función ya que lo que quería era que me devolviese la suma de los dos productos y por ello tuve que poner updateSubtotal(singleProduct)
  updateSubtotal(secondProduct)

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que tu respuesta necesita un poco de detalles, por favor edítala y agrega la información en la respuesta no en los comentarios. Saludos!